# Laravel worker terminated by SIGKILL not expected

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I am running worker with `Supervisor` on Laravel to run queued jobs where the job will be calling API & storing result into MongoDB. When I run the job, the worker will be killed after 6-7 API calls with only the error of `terminated by SIGKILL; not expected`. No other log is available. Anyone fixes this issue before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was due to the default `--timeout` setting for laravel queue. Because I didn't specify a time, it is automatically killed after 1 minute. Specifying a longer duration solved the issue.